# PHP array_chunk and limit per page

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I need to have a code like this example. I need to limit 3 category per li.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div> Categpry 1 </div>
      <div> Category 2 </div>
      <div> Category 3 </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div> Categpry 4 </div>
      <div> Category 5 </div>
      <div> Category 6 </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div> Categpry y </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Page 1 -> Category 1 [Items list], Category 2 [Items list], Category 3 [Items list]

Page 2 -> Category 4 [Items list], Category 5 [Items list], Category 6 [Items list]

Page x -> Category y [Items list].

```
<?php
$category = array(
   array('category_name' => 'Category1', 'channel_name' => 'Item 1'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category3', 'channel_name' => 'Item 2'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category1', 'channel_name' => 'Item 2'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category3', 'channel_name' => 'Item 1'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category2', 'channel_name' => 'Item 2'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category4', 'channel_name' => 'Item 4'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category5', 'channel_name' => 'Item 5'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category1', 'channel_name' => 'Item 6'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category3', 'channel_name' => 'Item 7'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category2', 'channel_name' => 'Item 8'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category4', 'channel_name' => 'Item 8'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category3', 'channel_name' => 'Item 3'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category5', 'channel_name' => 'Item 4'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category6', 'channel_name' => 'Item 2'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category2', 'channel_name' => 'Item 5'),
   array('category_name' => 'Category2', 'channel_name' => 'Item 7')
);
$newOptions = array();
  $i=1;
    foreach ($category as $option) {
      $cname = $option['category_name'];
      $itemname = $option['channel_name'];

      $newOptions[$cname][$i] = $itemname;
 $i++;
    }
?>
```

PHP array_chunk() can't help me or i not use it corectly.

How can i make this code to do like on top.

If you have a sugestion please help my. THX a lot.

Comment: Hmm... I spent 5min to read through but what's the problem here ..?

Comment: Sorry i edit my post. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pagesize = 3;

$category_pages = array_chunk($category, $pagesize);

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach ($category_pages as $page) {
    echo "\t<li>\n";
    foreach ($page as $category) {
        echo "\t\t<div> ", htmlspecialchars($category['category_name'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'), " </div>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

Comment: THX Prancis Avila. It work perfect but if i have 2 items at the ssame category then category is dublicated. Can you hel me with this ?